# SSRS 2008 how to get rid of white space from page breaks when parameters hidden?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, rdlc, rdl

Using SSRS 2008, I have created a report with multiple graphs and have separated each graph onto a separate page by adding page breaks at the end of each graph. The report runs ok, however if I add a parameter which hides a graph, an empty page in the middle of the report will be produced as a result. Im assuming that this is due to the page break that is still happening.

An example,

Page 1 - Graph 1

Page 2 - Graph 2

Page 3 - Graph 3

If I hide graph 2 using a parameter, I will get

Page 1 - Graph 1

Page 2 - Empty page with white space

Page 3 - Graph 3

However what I want is

Page 1 - Graph 1

Page 2 - Graph 3

I have tried adding in conditional statements to the disable property of the page break for each graph, this doesn't work. I have also tried setting the page parameter ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to true as well

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You can turn off page breaks in the middle table to test your theory. If you have any whitespace between the graphs make sure you remove that and have them right up against each other.

Comment: Do you have the page break property set as 'startandend'? When I select this I can emulate your problem. If I set it to 'end' then the report behaves in the way that you want.